# Apache POI crashes in tomcat but not in IDE

Tags: java, tomcat, jetty, apache-poi

**How do I create excel files using apache POI 3.16 on tomcat?**

I am writing a web application that creates an XLSX (using the XSSFWorkbook class) using apache POI 3.16, then simply writing it to an OutputStream. The intended behavior is to have the user click a button, then having the excel file directly written in the server's response so that the user can immediatly download it.

This works perfectly well in my development environment (using eclipse and jetty), but when i create a deployable .war file using maven, and deploy on it on my vanilla Tomcat, I obtain errors i cannot explain:

1. XLSX files with only one sheet work without problem.
2. Any file with more than sheet sends an error.

Furthermore, to try to solve this issue, I used a very basic example from the the documention (https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#NewWorkbook ) to write the following example:.

```
[...]
//this method is called from the onSubmit of a button being pressed
public void test(){
    //test writing a text file
    final List<String> lines = Arrays.asList("Line one", "Line two");
    final Path filepath = Paths.get("C:/path/to/my/file.txt");
    try {
        Files.write(filepath, lines, Charset.forName("UTF-8"), StandardOpenOption.CREATE);
    } catch (final Exception e) {
        InvoiceReportPage.logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
    }
    //test writing an excel file
    final Workbook wb1 = new XSSFWorkbook();
    wb1.createSheet("new sheet");
    try {
        final FileOutputStream fileOut1 = new FileOutputStream("C:/path/to/my/workbook.xlsx");
        wb1.write(fileOut1); //OpenXML4JException in tomcat
        fileOut1.close();
    } catch (final Exception e) {
        InvoiceReportPage.logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
    }
    finally {
        try {
            wb1.close(); //OpenXML4JException in tomcat
        }  catch(final Exception e) {
            InvoiceReportPage.logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        }

    }
}
[...]
```

This work perfectly fine in my development jetty server, but this time, regardless of the number of sheets, I get the same error as before, and I end up with XLSX files that are lacking some of their inner structure (this can be seen by opening them with 7zip), and are therefore corrupted and useless.

I made sure the server can read/write files in the directory "C:/path/to/my", and this can be attested by the the fact the text file "C:/path/to/my/file.txt" is correctly written to that folder.

Here is the stacktrace of the error i get when apache POI 3.16 fails to create the excel file in tomcat:

```
org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.OpenXML4JException: The part /docProps/core.xml fail to be saved in the stream with marshaller org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.internal.marshallers.ZipPackagePropertiesMarshaller@2a70f1c7
     at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage.saveImpl(ZipPackage.java:582)
     at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.save(OPCPackage.java:1557)
     at org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocument.write(POIXMLDocument.java:248)
     at com.itp.tomasot.webapp.wicket.InvoiceReportPage$InvoiceReportExcelSubmitLink.onSubmit(InvoiceReportPage.java:115)
     at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form.delegateSubmit(Form.java:1380)
     at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form.onFormSubmitted(Form.java:811)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
     at org.apache.wicket.RequestListenerInterface.invoke(RequestListenerInterface.java:183)
     at org.apache.wicket.request.target.component.listener.ListenerInterfaceRequestTarget.processEvents(ListenerInterfaceRequestTarget.java:73)
     at org.apache.wicket.request.AbstractRequestCycleProcessor.processEvents(AbstractRequestCycleProcessor.java:91)
     at com.itp.tomasot.webapp.wicket.WorkflowWebRequestCycleProcessor.processEvents(WorkflowWebRequestCycleProcessor.java:70)
     at org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.processEventsAndRespond(RequestCycle.java:1239)
     at org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.step(RequestCycle.java:1316)
     at org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.steps(RequestCycle.java:1418)
     at org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.request(RequestCycle.java:532)
     at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.doGet(WicketFilter.java:356)
     at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.doFilter(WicketFilter.java:201)
     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
     at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:394)
     at org.springframework.security.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilterHttp(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:235)
     at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
     at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:406)
     at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:185)
     at org.springframework.security.util.FilterToBeanProxy.doFilter(FilterToBeanProxy.java:99)
     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
     at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
     at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
     at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
     at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
     at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
     at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
     at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2440)
     at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2429)
     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
     at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I'm using java 1.7 with compliance level 1.6.

The tomcat server is located on a windows server 2008 R2 server, and the technology used by the website is wicket 1.3.6. (i know it's ancient, but i can't do anything about it for now).

It should be noted that I tested this problem with a local tomcat on my local windows 7 Entreprise machine, and the problem is the exactly the same as on the test server.

My web application is bundled in .war file using the following maven dependency :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
    <version>3.16</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
    <version>3.16</version>
</dependency>
```

**Edit:**
When running the web application in tomcat, i noticed an error appearing only in tomcat's console (and not in any other log file):

```
Error
  DOMSource cannot be processed: check that saxon8-dom.jar is on the classpath
```

This lead me to this issue on stackoverflow: [Apache POI error when not in IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32725532/apache-poi-error-when-not-in-ide)

However, i don't have LibreOffice installed (and never did) on any machine running tomcat, and anyway, the solution from that issue remains unclear: what is causing dependencies to break in tomcat only, and not jetty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So in the end, this is how I solved the issue: since tomcat complained the saxon librairy was missing, I simply added it as a dependency in the pom.xml of my maven project:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.saxon</groupId>
    <artifactId>saxon-dom</artifactId>
    <version>8.7</version>
</dependency>
```

As soon as I deployed with this dependency included, POI started working correctly in tomcat.

What remains unclear is

1) Why jetty's depencies are different from tomcat's. Saxon isn't in my CLASS_PATH or any obvious environment variable. So my guess is it really IS is there somewhere as an implicit dependency in my development environment, though i can't find where, but not in tomcat's, which is more self-contained.

2) Why saxon isn't mentioned at all as a dependency for apache POI in the official documentation.

Comment: Saxon isn't required for Apache POI to work! Apache POI just needs a working standards compliant XML parser in your JVM

Comment: Could it be then that the JVM being used by my tomcast server doesn't have any working standards compliant XML parser? And if so, why does it complain specifically about not finding saxon?