# Azure AD Authentication gives java.lang.Exception: Unable to find any tokens in RSTR

Tags: java, azure, azure-authentication

i am implementing the Azure AD Authentication.
while calling the below method,

```
 Future<AuthenticationResult> future =
          context.acquireToken(GRAPH_MICROSOFT_URL, clientId, username, password, null);
```

it gives exception on my console.

```
Error 
  DOMSource cannot be processed: check that saxon9-dom.jar is on the classpath
net.sf.saxon.trans.XPathException: DOMSource cannot be processed: check that saxon9-dom.jar is on the classpath
    at net.sf.saxon.event.Sender.send(Sender.java:251)
    at net.sf.saxon.IdentityTransformer.transform(IdentityTransformer.java:30)
    at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.WSTrustResponse.innerXml(WSTrustResponse.java:228)
    at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.WSTrustResponse.parseToken(WSTrustResponse.java:159)
    at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.WSTrustResponse.parse(WSTrustResponse.java:111)
    at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.WSTrustRequest.execute(WSTrustRequest.java:74)
    at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.WSTrustRequest.execute(WSTrustRequest.java:88)
    at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AcquireTokenCallable.processPasswordGrant(AcquireTokenCallable.java:137)
    at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AcquireTokenCallable.execute(AcquireTokenCallable.java:60)
    at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AcquireTokenCallable.execute(AcquireTokenCallable.java:38)
    at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AdalCallable.call(AdalCallable.java:47)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Anyone having idea why this exception comes. i am usin the below jar.

```
implementation group: 'com.microsoft.azure', name: 'adal4j', version: '1.6.6'
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code

```
ClientCredential credential = new ClientCredential("client_ID", "client_secret");
AuthenticationContext context = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.windows.net/tenant_ID/oauth2/token",true,service);
FutureResult = context.acquireToken("https://graph.windows.net", credential, null);
        while(!(FutureResult.isDone()))
        {}
        accesstoken=FutureResult.get().getAccessToken();
```

The message(`DOMSource cannot be processed: check that saxon9-dom.jar is on the classpath`) is from an older version of Saxon, and you could solve it either by putting saxon9-dom on the classpath as suggested, or by replacing the Saxon jar file with a more recent release.  For more details refer this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15438011/domsource-cannot-be-processed-check-that-saxon9-dom-jar-is-on-the-classpath)

Follow this [github](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-java-webapp-openidconnect) to for more details